# complete.cases and anyNA do not detect NA in row?

Tags: r

Why do neither `complete.cases` or `anyNA` not return FALSE for row 1? Based on their documentation it seems like they should... am I reading the docs wrong?

```
csv<-data.frame(c(100,50,100),c(1,1,1),c(NA,12,NA))
csv$complete<-apply(csv,1,function(x){x[1]==100 && x[2]==1 && complete.cases(x)}) #check that column_1==100, and column_2=1, and no missing values in the row

csv$complete2<-apply(csv,1,function(x){x[1]==100 && x[2]==1 && anyNA(x, recursive = FALSE)})

> csv
c.100..50..100. c.1..1..1. c.NA..12..NA. complete complete2
1             100          1            NA     TRUE      TRUE
2              50          1            12    FALSE     FALSE
3             100          1            NA     TRUE      TRUE
```

Comment: You can consider this. `TRUE && complete.cases(c(1,2,NA))` which is `TURE && c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)` and returns `TRUE`. I guess only the first TRUE is used when you use `&&`, you can try `&` with all in the function.

Comment: `anyNA` seems to be working as you'd expect (TRUE if there's at least one NA and FALSE otherwise). As @Psidom shows, `complete.cases` returns a vector with a separate truth value for each element of the row. `isTRUE(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE))` returns `FALSE`, so @Psidom may be correct that R is looking at only the first value of that vector. In fact, if you switch columns 1 and 3, your first logical test returns `FALSE FALSE FALSE`, which also suggests that only the first element of the vector returned by `complete.cases` is being used.

Comment: Interesting, so why doesnt replacing `anyNA()` with `!isTRUE(anyNA(x, recursive = FALSE))` give the correct result? I just tested it with `isTRUE(anyNA(c(1,2,NA)))` and it returned TRUE as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first apparent anomaly to your eyes represents a failure to understand the difference between `&&` and `&`. The anonymous function was given a 3-element vector and `complete.cases` returns this for the first row:

```
complete.cases( c(100,1,NA) )
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

The `&&` function only deals with the first item of every vector given to it, so it returned TRUE for the first row. Arguably a warning might have been appropriate here.  If you had wanted something that tests for a lack of `NA`'s and it happens to be a vector under consideration, I would have used `all( !is.na(.))`

```
csv$complete<-apply(csv,1,function(x){x[1]==100 && x[2]==1 && all(!is.na((x))  )}) 

csv$complete2<-apply(csv,1,function(x){x[1]==100 && x[2]==1 && anyNA(x, recursive = FALSE)})

> csv
  c.100..50..100. c.1..1..1. c.NA..12..NA. complete complete2
1             100          1            NA    FALSE      TRUE
2              50          1            12    FALSE     FALSE
3             100          1            NA    FALSE      TRUE
```

The anyNA should have been negated with "!" if (as it appears from context) you expected all of complete2 to also be FALSE.